# Excel Automatically Numbering Sheets that Have the Same Name

Tags: vba, excel

hope everyone is doing good! I have a quick question concerning excel and sheet names. Currently I have a macro assigned to a forum control button on my template invoice page that when clicked will make a duplicate sheet named after cell E7 (the project name) + the word "Invoice" at the end of it. But since there will be more than one invoice per project, I would like the macro to include some code where if it finds a duplicate name, it will automatically start numbering them from two. So for example, I use the macro to create "Project A Invoice". If I use it again to create another one, I want it to be named "Project A Invoice(2)" automatically instead of giving me an error message. Here's what I have so far:

```
Sub invoice_export_test()
Dim sName As String
Dim wks As Worksheet
Worksheets("Invoice").Copy after:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
Set wks = ActiveSheet
Do While sName <> wks.Name
    sName = Range("E7") + " Invoice"
    wks.Name = sName
    On Error GoTo 0
Loop
Range("C7:D7").Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
    :=xlBetween
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .IMEMode = xlIMEModeNoControl
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Button 1")).Select
Selection.Delete
Set wks = Nothing
End Sub
```

Everything after the loop is irrelevant to this question (its there to delete the forum control button and data validation), but I included it just in case. The code is probably messy since I am not too experienced with VBA and used a few tutorials to work this out, so please forgive me for that haha.

Thank you in advanced for your time/help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a couple functions to help yourself out:

```
Function GetUniqueName(strProject As String) As String

    ' If this is the first time it's being used, just return it without a number...
    If Not SheetNameExists(strProject & " Invoice") Then
        GetUniqueName = strProject & " Invoice"
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Otherwise, suffix the sheet name with a number, starting at 2...
    Dim i As Long, strName As String
    i = 1

    Do
        i = i + 1
        strName = strProject & " Invoice (" & i & ")"
    Loop While SheetNameExists(strName)

    GetUniqueName = strName

End Function

Function SheetNameExists(strName As String) As Boolean
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In Worksheets
        If StrComp(sh.Name, strName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            SheetNameExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

Then you can change your code from:

```
Dim sName As String
Dim wks As Worksheet
Worksheets("Invoice").Copy after:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
Set wks = ActiveSheet
Do While sName <> wks.Name
    sName = Range("E7") + " Invoice"
    wks.Name = sName
    On Error GoTo 0
Loop
```

To:

```
Worksheets("Invoice").Copy after:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
Worksheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = GetUniqueName(Range("E7"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the in depth answer! Do all the functions go where the subs are in the VBA window? Or is there a specific place to define functions? Thanks again!

Comment: You can throw them into a `Module` so that they're available for all sheets in your workbook.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works like a charm. This has been giving me a headache for a while, so I can't thank you enough for assisting me with this.